# constructing QR-like one way function

Tags: one-way-function, modular-arithmetic

I am wondering whether the following form is a one way function with collision resistance:
$$ax^2+by^2 \mod p$$
where $a$ and $b$ are given, and $p$ is a prime number.

Since the QR (quadratic residue) $x^2 \mod p$ is one way, $ax^2 \mod p$ is also one way.
The same goes for $by^2$.

So, my guess is that the form $ax^2+by^2 \mod p$ is one way. Is that correct?

A few more follow-up questions:

1. How to formalize a proof that a numeric equation is one way?
2. Does anyone know an archive collecting all of known one way functions?
3. If $ax^2+by^2 \mod p$ is not one way, how about $a^2x+b^2y \mod p$?
4. What is instead of a prime $p$ we have a composite number (possibly with certain assumptions on its factorization)?

Comment: I think you made a mistake, $x^2 \mod p$ is not (generally) one-way, there are efficient algorithms to take modular square roots modulo prime numbers (it's much harder for composites, though). Did you mean $a^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} = \binom{a}{p}$ which then obviously lacks collision resistance..

Comment: you are right, i made a mistake, all of the boave modulos are mod N, N is a composite

Comment: Take care. As the special case, we can consider $x^2+hy^2 \bmod{n}$.  
The Ong-Schnorr-Shamir signature is based on $x^2+hy^2 \equiv m \pmod{n}$.
Pollad and Schnorr cryptanalyzed this scheme without factoring $n$.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I replace $p$ with a composite $n$.
The answer is *no*.

The problem is determining whether $f(x,y) = a x^2 + b y^2 \bmod{n}$ is one-way or not.
We want to find $(x',y')$ such that $f(x',y') = z$, given $a, b, n$ and $z = a x^2 + b y^2 \bmod{n}$.

Let us consdier $f'(x,y) = x^2 + h y^2 \bmod{n}$, where $h = b a^{-1} \bmod{n}$.
The problem is now finding $(x',y')$ satisfying $f'(x',y') = m$, given $m = z a^{-1} \bmod{n}$, $h = b a^{-1} \bmod{n}$, and $n$.

The problem is a basis of the Ong-Schnorr-Shamir signature (STOC 1984, CRYPTO 1984).
We already know that [Pollad and Schnorr (1987)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1987.1057350) cryptanalyzed this scheme without factoring $n$.
The algorithm and example is available in [a short note written by Jeffrey Shallit](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/pols.ps).